"How to activate the system app 'Setup Wizard' 'com.google.android.setupwizard' on Android via ADB without root?" 'Error: java.lang.SecurityException'
The command adb shell pm enable com.google.android.setupwizard returns an error:
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Shell cannot change component state for com.google.android.setupwizard/null to 1.
The command adb shell pm default-state com.google.android.setupwizard returns an error:
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Shell cannot change component state for com.google.android.setupwizard/null to 0.
Any suggestions for attempts?

What are you trying to do and why? The setup wizard should be enabled by default.

I'm trying to reverse a bootloop that happened after disabling the Setup Wizard app through the system interface, however, the two commands for this presented these errors, in theory the 'adb pm default-state' command was supposed to work without errors, but it didn't work , I don't know if due to the bootloop the system cannot identify the default state of the Setup Wizard, since I have 20 seconds to send the adb shell command before android restarts the bootloop process.

You should add the command you used to disable the setup wizard, otherwise it is not clear which command may work to re-enable it, because there are different ways to disable a componnet and thus different ways to reactivate it, e.g. pm uninstall see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63859597/150978

I disabled it through the application: Configuration, Applications, Setup Wizard, Disable, Force Stop, Clear Data. I tried 'adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.android.stk i32 1 i32 0'
and 'adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.google.android.setupwizard i32 1 i32 1' and it had no effect
adb shell pm install-existing com.google.android.setupwizard
There is no 'install-existing' parameter.
